# Full Calendar not showing some rows when slot duration is set while rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to figure out why full calendar is not showing some rows. I tried setting the slotDuration to 5, 10 minutes in that case, it works but in 15, 30 minutes it doesn't. I also saw that while rendering it applies `.fc-minor` class on adjacent rows which are not showing.

Does anyone know why it's happening ?

[image: Full Calendar Bug]

```
var calendarOptions = {
  header: {
    left: 'prev today',
    center: 'title',//'agendaWeek,agendaFourDay',
    right: 'next, month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
  },
  columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
  eventColor:"#208454",
  timezone: 'Australia/Sydney',
  slotDuration: '00:30:00',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had below property set in my custom.scss which was preventing the rendering of adjacent events correctly.

```
.fc-slats td {
    height: 1px !important;
}
```